# How to replace "and/or" in sentences with multiple terms?

Tags: technical-writing, legal

When writing a legal document, what is the proper way to replace and/or in a list with more than two terms to remove ambiguity?

For example, if I just have two terms:

> deliver apples and/or oranges

could be replaced with:

> deliver apples, oranges or both

so the valid results are:

[ "apples", "oranges", "apples and oranges"]

Now, I would like to do the same for the following sentence:

> deliver apples, oranges and/or pears

So the valid results are:

[ "apples", "oranges", "pears", "apples and oranges", "apples and pears", "oranges and pears", "apples, oranges and pears" ]

Comment: You might consider asking this on [the Law site](http://law.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will ask my question in that site as well

Comment: Does the `,` in your `apples, oranges and/or pears` example signify an _and_ or an _or_?

Answer (score 2):

From a purely stylistic point of view: "any combination of: apples, oranges, pears"

But you say this is for a legal document and lawyers may construe ambiguity where ordinary reasonable people would not, so if your question is a "will it hold up in court" kind of question, this is the wrong place to ask.